# Category names and the chart are not aligned in polar chart, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If I do not add categories, it will by default number them from 0 to n, and these numbers are aligned with the lines starting from the center.

```
xAxis: {
  /*  categories: ['teemo', 'ryze', 'yasuo', 'vayne', 'maokai', 'poppy'] */
},
```

When the name of the categories are present, they will be put inbetween this lines.  Is it possible to place them like the one with the default numeration

https://jsfiddle.net/fps38oyr/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['teemo', 'ryze', 'yasuo', 'vayne', 'maokai', 'poppy']
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
    pointPlacement: 'between'
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Line',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  }, {
    type: 'area',
    name: 'Area',
    data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In can be done easily using one of these approaches:

1. set categories and `xAxis.tickmarkPlacement = 'on'`

---

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['teemo', 'ryze', 'yasuo', 'vayne', 'maokai', 'poppy'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
  }
```

2. use `xAxis.labels.formatter` callback to swap numbers with categories.

---

```
  var categories = ['teemo', 'ryze', 'yasuo', 'vayne', 'maokai', 'poppy'];
  ...

  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return categories[this.value];
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demos:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yvLgtxrw/1/
- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tv1s85fj/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter